# Modifiying a Django view for a certain project

Tags: python, django, django-comments

So I simply want to use the delete() from the django.contrib.comments.views.moderation module, but only allowing the users with permission to delete their comments. In order to do this, all I have to do is uncomment `#@permission_required("comments.delete_comment")`, but I want to be able to do this without modifying the django framework. How can I modify/extend this view to my project? I guess the better question would be, what is the best way to change the setting for the delete() without changing anything in the django framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line is only commented out because Django 1.1 maintains compatibility with Python 2.3 which doesn't support the decorator (`@`) syntax. But the view is decorated with `permission_required` nonetheless (with syntax that is compatible with Python 2.3), as you can see [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.1.1/django/contrib/comments/views/moderation.py#L85). Django 1.2 will drop support for Python 2.3 and will switch to the `@`-syntax. This is already visible on [trunk](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/comments/views/moderation.py#L36).

Bottom line: you have to do nothing, as Django does already exactly what you want (this seems to be a recurring theme with Django :-) ).

Comment: Okay, it was working fine. However, I want to be able to give permission for non-staff users to be able to delete their own comments. How can I go about with doing that?

Comment: That's a completely different question. If my answer was satisfactory with respect to your original question, please mark it as such and write a new question. Thanks :)